# Accessing hadoop distributed file system from eclipse using java

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

Here is the code for accessing the HDFS using java

```
         try {

            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.set("fs.defaultFS","hdfs://192.168.28.153:9000/");
            FileSystem dfs = FileSystem.get(config);
             Path pt = new Path("hdfs://192.168.28.153:9000/user/hduser/wordcountinput/input.txt");
             config.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dfs.open(pt)));
             String line;
             line = br.readLine();
             while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                 System.out.println(line);
                 line = br.readLine();
             }
```

And after executing i am getting the followed exception:

```
WARNING: org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.EventCounter is deprecated. Please use org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter in all the
 log4j.properties files. No FileSystem for scheme:
 hdfsjava.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs
 at
 org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2138)
 org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:80)
```

Is there is any connection issue? I need help on this so that i can proceed further. Is any resource is missing or something else.

Comment: I see multiple misconfigured versions of Hadoop Jars in your Eclipse... Please use the exact version of Hadoop that you have installed and please use Maven / Gradle instead of manually adding Jars to your classpath

Comment: i have hadoop 2.8.1 but the configuration is of 2.6.4 
is this the issue ??

Comment: Well, yes. The jars are required to match your installation. But I see you have `hadoop-aws` (which you don't need if you are not using AWS / S3), two `hadoop-common`'s, `hadoop-core-0.20` (super old), `hadoop-core-1.1.2` (still old, but not even Hadoop 2.x)...

Comment: oh.... ok let me update it... if still the same problem or else i'll catch you

Comment: External Jar: **hadoop-core-1.1.2.jar** 
`try {
         
         Configuration config = new Configuration();
         config.set("fs.defaultFS","hdfs://192.168.28.155:9000/");
         FileSystem dfs = FileSystem.get(config);
            Path pt = new Path("hdfs://192.168.28.155:9000/user/hduser/wordcountinput/input.txt");
            config.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
            ............`
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
 at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>

Comment: Still not sure why you are using Hadoop1.x libraries... Which Hadoop version did you actually install? Please use that version, and again, please use Maven, not manually adding JAR files

Comment: Start here. http://bytequest.net/building-a-mapreduce-maven-project-with-eclipse/

Comment: is ma Path is 
"Path pt = new Path("hdfs://192.168.28.155:9000/usr/hduser/wordcountinput/input.txt");" 

& if i want to access hadoop file system from windows and code remain the same the error is as followed: 

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1107)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:411)

Comment: can u please guide me.... what are the hadoop 2.8.1 library for this code, i'll download it and add it

Comment: and that link is for WordCount example using mapreduce but this code is simple

Comment: hadoop version is 2.8.1

Comment: Forget about MapReduce... I was pointing you how to start a Maven project... Edit the versions just to use 2.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the specific jars. There are bunches of inappropriate jars.